# How orgineze two port for squid server

Tags: centos, proxy, squid

I have squid server installed on centos 6.x. Squid server authenticates users by LDAP server on port 3128. Can I open other one port for Squid server without any authenticating. How?

Answer (score 0):

In your main configuration file (squid.conf), or in the file where you define the ports, simply add a second `http_port` directive with the desired port, e.g.:

```
http_port 3128
http_port 3129
```

Reload squid and you should be fine. Verify that it worked with `netstat -lntp | grep squid`